# calculate average from APi in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, json-rpc, ipfs

I want to create a code that can calculate the average of numbers. the numbers should come from an API or IPFS in the JSON format file.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: To access an api from solidity you have to use an oracle like chainlink.

Comment: but I don't have kovan public testnet to deploy

Comment: You can run your own oracle https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57968/tutorial-to-understand-technical-details-of-oracles-in-ethereum. Some service offchain will run and send to the contract the numbers, and the contract will compute the result.